# Overload operator<<

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I would like to overload `operator<<` like this:

```
ostringstream oss;
MyDate a(2000, 1, 2);
oss << dateFormat("%Y/%m/%d") << a;
assert(oss.str() == "2000-01-02");
```

so that the date at `a` will be formatted to specific format. How to achieve this?

Comment: Is that `f` supposed to be `a`?

Comment: Yes, edited in source code

Comment: When then go ahead and try writing it yourself.

Comment: What you want is called a custom stream manipulator.  It is explained in detail here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599/c-custom-stream-manipulator-that-changes-next-item-on-stream

Answer (score 3):

In order to store custom state in a stream, you need to use the `xalloc` static function to get a unique index, and then either `pword` to get a pointer at that index (allocated specifically for each stream it is used on), or `iword` to get an integer at that index(allocated specifically for each stream it is used on). In your case, you will probably want `pword`. You can use the pointer returned by `pword` to point to a dynamically allocated object which stores the formatting information.

```
struct DateFormatter
{
    // The implementation of this class (e.g. parsing the format string)
    // is a seperate issue. If you need help with it, you can ask another
    // question

    static int xalloc_index;
};

int DateFormatter::xalloc_index = std::ios_base::xalloc();

void destroy_date_formatter(std::ios_base::event evt, std::ios_base& io, int idx)
{
    if (evt == std::ios_base::erase_event) {
        void*& vp = io.pword(DateFormatter::xalloc_index);
        delete (DateFormatter*)(vp);
    }
}

DateFormatter& get_date_formatter(std::ios_base& io) {
    void*& vp = io.pword(DateFormatter::xalloc_index);
    if (!vp) {
        vp = new DateFormatter;
        io.register_callback(destroy_date_formatter, 0);
    }
    return *static_cast<DateFormatter*>(vp);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DateFormatter& df) {
    get_date_formatter(os) = df;
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyDate& date)
{
    DateFormatter& df = get_date_formatter(os);

    // format output according to df

    return os;
}

int main() {
    MyDate a ( 2000, 1, 2 );
    std::cout << DateFormatter("%Y/%m/%d") << a;
}
```

This is the standard method. It is terrible, in my opinion. I much prefer an alternative approach, which is to pass the date object together with the formatting as a single object. For example:

```
class DateFormatter
{
    const MyDate* date;
    std::string format_string;
    DateFormatter(const MyDate& _date, std::string _format_string)
        :date(&_date)
        ,format_string(_format_string)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DateFormatter& df) {
        // handle formatting details here
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyDate a ( 2000, 1, 2 );
    std::cout << DateFormatter(a, "%Y/%m/%d");
}
```

Comment: How/when does the DateFormatter get deleted in the first example?

Comment: @ksfone: If you mean when is the delete statement used on it, never. Its lifetime ends with the program.

Comment: @kfsone: You know what? This is bad. I was thinking that only one of these objects would be created, but I just realized that one will be created for every stream that is created (which could be a problem with something like stringstreams, which might get created over and over). I don't do this often, so I forgot the proper way to do it. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like that (using static variable):

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyDate
{
    MyDate(int y, int m, int d): year{y}, month{m}, day{d} {}

    int year{};
    int month{};
    int day{};
};

class DateFormatter
{
public:
    DateFormatter(const std::string & format)
    {
        format_ = format;
    }

    static const std::string & format()
    {
        return format_;
    }

private:
    static std::string format_;
};

std::string DateFormatter::format_ = {"Default Format"};

std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & stream, const DateFormatter &)
{
    return stream;
}

std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & stream, const MyDate & date)
{
    auto currentFormat = DateFormatter::format();
    // some code using current format ...
    return stream << currentFormat << " - " << date.year << "/" << date.month << "/" << date.day;
}

int main(void)
{
    MyDate date{2016,4,18};
    std::cout << date << std::endl;
    std::cout << DateFormatter("New format") << date << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what if someone wants to write to two different streams using two different formats concurrently?