# what is the real return type of std::setw, std::setfill and so on?

Tags: c++

I'm curious of the real return type of std::setw and std::setfill

As we see references, their datatype of return value is "undefined".
However, Is it possible to declare a function without return type?

In a situation that I have to develop a method supplying extended features for 'cout' or 'cin',
and this method should be called like

```
cout << foo(32, 'A', 0.00f) << "Hello world!";
```

How should I declare the method?

Comment: The method should return an `std::ostream`. Also, `std::setw` has UNSPECIFIED return type (it's implementation defined)

Comment: @Brandon: No, it shouldn't. `operator<<` returns an `ostream`, but `setw` and `setfill` do not.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley; He is asking what should `foo` return. I am saying it should return `std::ostream` in order to chain it like that with `std::cout`. I specifically said the other functions he mentioned is `unspecified` (implementation defined). Not sure how you missed that.

Comment: @Brandon: What `ostream` should `foo` return, exactly?

Comment: @Brandon: Why should it return `cout`? What would that achieve?

Comment: Then, if I have to develop the "foo" method to make the following text look different, What should I do? // e.g. cout < < foo(1) < < "Hello"; should print like "H.e.l.l.o"

Comment: @BenjaminLindley "unspecified" is different to "implementation-defined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) et al is unspecified because each C++ implementation may decide to do it differently, so there's no one answer - you have to survey the compilers/versions you're interested in.

Looking at the libstdc++ used with GCC, we see:

```
00214   struct _Setw { int _M_n; };
00215 
00216   /**
00217    *  @brief  Manipulator for @c width.
00218    *  @param  n  The new width.
00219    *
00220    *  Sent to a stream object, this manipulator calls @c width(n) for
00221    *  that object.
00222   */
00223   inline _Setw 
00224   setw(int __n)
00225   { return { __n }; }
```

`_Setw` is a small struct to capture the width parameter, and which `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, _Setw)` and `...>>...` can then handle to set the width in the stream:

```
00227   template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
00228     inline basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
00229     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, _Setw __f)
00230     {
00231       __is.width(__f._M_n);
00232       return __is; 
00233     }
00234 
00235   template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
00236     inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
00237     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, _Setw __f)
00238     {
00239       __os.width(__f._M_n);
00240       return __os; 
00241     }
```

> As we see references, their datatype of return value is "undefined".

It's *unspecified*, not undefined.

> However, Is it possible to declare a function without return type?

No - every function must have a return type, even if only `void`.

> In a situation that I have to develop a method supplying extended features for 'cout' or 'cin', and this method should be called like

```
cout << foo(32, 'A', 0.00f) << "Hello world!";
```

> How should I declare the method?

You can do something similar and have function `foo` return an object that you write streaming operators for.  Those streaming functions should then manipulate the stream: you'll need to use [`iword`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword) and [`xalloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/xalloc) to give the streams extra state to track the potentially modified behaviours you're going to add - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599/c-custom-stream-manipulator-that-changes-next-item-on-stream).

Comment: Then, if I have to develop the "foo" method to make the following text look different, What should I do? // e.g. cout < < foo(1) < < "Hello"; should print like "H.e.l.l.o"

Comment: See the just-appended information in my answer.  Cheers

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your kind answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: @LucianoJeong If you're satisfied with this answer, you should accept it (green tick).

Answer (score 0):

It is unspecified, or in other words, not specified in the C++ standard and depends on your library implementation. More on that [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

You can't declare your own function to manipulate the insertion/extraction operators unless you overload them to accept a new type.