# Deferring cout output until just prior to the next output

Tags: c++

I have some C++ console programs that display progress information on the last line of output, at regular intervals.

This progress line is cleared prior to writing the next *real* output (or updated progress information); this could be from a number of different places in the source, and I'm currently clearing the progress line on each one, e.g.:

```
cout << clearline << "Some real output" << endl;
...
cout << clearline << "Some other real output" << endl;
...
cout << clearline << setw(4) << ++icount << ") " << ... << endl;
...
cout << clearline << "Progress info number " << ++iprog << flush;
```

Here, 'clearline' is some (system dependent) string like "\r\33[2K" which clears the current last line.

I would prefer something cleaner, that localises source changes to the actual line that's going to be cleared, like simply:

```
cout << "Progress info number " << ++iprog << flush << defer_clearline;
```

where 'defer_clearline' causes the writing of 'clearline' to be deferred until just prior to the next cout output, wherever and whatever that happens to be. I then wouldn't need to use 'clearline' on all the other lines.

I thought it might be possible to do this if 'defer_clearline' is a manipulator, and/or using xalloc() and iword().
But I've not managed to get anything that works.
Is it possible to do this sort of thing, and if so how?

2020-12-30: edited to include missing 'flush's.

Comment: Personally I would write an `overwrite_cout` object that wraps `cout` and use `clearline` as the first thing passed to it so that every time you use it, it automatically cleans the previous line.

Comment: Might be possible to implement a custom [`std::streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) that provides the desired behaviour.  It could keep track of the number of characters written on the line, map '\n' to '\r' etc.  Fairly basic but... ?

Comment: Related/dupe: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599/c-custom-stream-manipulator-that-changes-next-item-on-stream)

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily setup an `std::cout` wrapper:

```
// Declare the empty struct clear_line and instantiate the object cls
struct clear_line { } cls;

class out {
private:
    std::ostream &strm = std::cout;
    bool is_next_clear = false;
public:
    template <typename T>
    out& operator<<(const T& obj) {
        if(is_next_clear) {
            strm << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl; // clear logic
            is_next_clear = false;
        }
        
        strm << obj;
        return *this;
    }
    
    out& operator<<(const clear_line& _) {
        is_next_clear = true;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This pretty simply stores an `is_next_clear` bool for whether or not the next regular output should be cleared. Then, in the general case (the templated `operator<<()`), we run your clear logic and flip the `is_next_clear` flag if applicable. Then just output as usual.

Then, the `operator<<()` is overloaded for the case of a `clear_line` object. So if one of those is sent, we know to flip the `is_next_clear` flag, but not actually output anything.

Here's an example use:

```
int main() {
    out o;
    o << "Some real output" << cls;
    o << "Some other real output";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here it is in action: https://ideone.com/0Dzwlv

---

If you want to use `endl`, you'll need to add a special overload for it as this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134467/2602718

```
// this is the type of std::cout
typedef std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > CoutType;

// this is the function signature of std::endl
typedef CoutType& (*StandardEndLine)(CoutType&);

// define an operator<< to take in std::endl
out& operator<<(StandardEndLine manip)
{
    // call the function, but we cannot return its value
    manip(strm);
    return *this;
}
```

Live example: https://ideone.com/ACUMOo

Comment: That works as shown, but if I change:  
    o << "Some other real output";  
to:  
    o << "Some other real output" << endl;  
gcc gives:error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'out' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')

Comment: Ahh @Dunc `std::endl` is special for `std::cout`. You can read more here ([std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<<](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134467/2602718)). Essentially you'll need to add a special `endl` for the wrapper. Let me edit to add that...

Comment: @Dunc I've updated to include that example