# how to use std::num_put for custom pointer output formatting?

Tags: c++, iostream

###### TLDR;

Default output of pointers with c++ iostream is of the form `0xdeadbeef`.
What I want is pointers to be output in the form `#xdeadbeef`.

###### Problem

For testing purposes I output internal data of some c++ program in form of s-expressions, so I can have in the future the option to use Common Lisp to reason about the output.
Now, hex numbers are written in the form `#xdeadbeef` and iostream default is using the C/C++ typical `0x...` syntax.

So, after a bit of reading, I think I am close to finding a solution... only, at least on cppreference.com, there is not enough (demo code or explanations) to allow me to understand, how I am exactly supposed to solve this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

struct lispy_num_put : std::num_put<char> {
  iter_type do_put(iter_type s, std::ios_base& f,
           char_type fill, const void* p) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << p;
    std::string zwoggle{oss.str()};
    if (zwoggle.length() > 2 && zwoggle.starts_with("0x")) {
      zwoggle[0] = '#';
    }
    // ... NOW WHAT TO DO??? I.e how to send the string along?
  }
};
// ...
```

As you can see, I now have the string representation of how I want to see the pointer in the output. Only it is unclear to me, how to send that string now into the output stream.

Later, I will have to use some `imbue()` thingy to make this struct used by my output stream. I think, that part I can figure out myself.

Comment: A simple workaround would be to define a function/struct wrapper to do the output instead of modifying the default behavior.

Comment: Looks like like you can use the default `do_put` -- see [C++ custom stream manipulator that changes next item on stream - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599/c-custom-stream-manipulator-that-changes-next-item-on-stream).

Comment: @user202729 I assumed this is the idiomatic way of this use case, supported by STL...

Comment: I think changing the behavior of printing pointer globally would be quite unexpected by the programmer however. Wrapping in struct would make it explicit (like `std::cout<< PrintPointerAsLisp{my_pointer};`)

Comment: This is an example for a whole class of use cases, which are not really explained (at least I did not find stuff while googling...). The same solution could also apply for a reincarnated roman emperor who wants to see their numbers as roman literals ;) The problem is, how to use `std::num_put` for alternate formatting...

Comment: Maybe make the question ask for specific clarification regarding that answer instead. Somehow I find it okay to understand (it gets the user's input in the parameter, then print the modified output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `iter_type s` parameter to output characters.

```
*s++ = '#'; // outputs a hash 
while (...) *s++ = ...; // outputs digits
return s;
```

Comment: could it be that easy?! Verifying ... ;)  `for (auto c : zwoggle) {
      *s++ = c;
    }
    return s;` ?

Comment: I get a warning: `mem-ref-test.cpp:19:13: warning: 'lispy_num_put::do_put' hides overloaded virtual functions [-Woverloaded-virtual]` - is that to be expected?

Comment: and... I still see 0x... in the output instead of #x...

Comment: do_put should be a const function. Try adding `const override`.

Comment: Bingo! Now it works - thanks a lot!