# How to create a manipulator that would call a specific function in the next object in the stream?

Tags: c++, stream, manipulators

Suppose I have a class as follows:

```
class A
{
...private members
public:
void write_text(std::ostream& os); //writes members as text
void write_binary(std::ostream& os); //writes objects as binary
};
```

How do I create a manipulator that like `text` and `binary` depending on which I can call appropriate function `write_text()` or `write_binary()` to write to filestream like so:

```
std::ofstream file1("textfile.txt");
std::ofstream file2("binfile.bin");

A obj; // assume obj has data members set 
file1<<text<<obj; // here obj.write_text() should be invoked 
file2<<binary<<obj; // here obj.write_binary() should be invoked
```

Do I need to store something like a state or a variable in the stream like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599/c-custom-stream-manipulator-that-changes-next-item-on-stream) to be able to do this or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Well, yes, stream manipulators generally change the state of the stream.    That is sort of necessary for the manipulator to have an enduring effect on the stream (e.g. to cause a subsequent operation to behave differently).

Comment: @Peter No idea how to do it except for standard manipulators like `std::hex1 etc. Do you have a tutorial in mind that would help? I don't know much about `standard library` implementations like `char traits` etc. So that example is not a lot of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary ways the standard uses to manipulate input & output operations.

##### 1. Storing values in the stream state

You can store formatting state within streams by using [`std::ios_base::xalloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/xalloc).
This gives you a `long` and `void*` value in each stream that you can access with [`iword()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword) / [`pword()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/pword) .

This is the same mechanism that standard io manipulators like [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex), [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) use.

Note that if you change the stream state it'll stay that way until you change it again, e.g.:

```cpp
std::cout << std::hex << 16; // will be outputted in hexadecimal
std::cout << 12; // will still be outputted in hexadecimal

std::cout << std::dec << 16; // will be outputted in decimal
std::cout << 12; // still decimal
```

You could e.g. implement it like this for your `A` class:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    void write_text(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "TEXT";
    }

    void write_binary(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "BINARY";
    }
};

// this gives us the unique index we need for pword() / iword()
inline int getAFormatIndex() {
    static int idx = std::ios_base::xalloc();
    return idx;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& a) {
    std::ostream::sentry s{os};
    if(!s) return os;
    
    if(os.iword(getAFormatIndex()) == 0)
        a.write_text(os);
    else
        a.write_binary(os);

    return os;
}

struct text_t {};
struct binary_t {};

inline constexpr text_t text;
inline constexpr binary_t binary;

// change to text mode
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, text_t const&) {
    os.iword(getAFormatIndex()) = 0;
    return os;
}

// change to binary mode
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, binary_t const&) {
    os.iword(getAFormatIndex()) = 1;
    return os;
}
```

- The `operator<<` for `A` checks which format type is currently stored in the stream (0 for text, 1 for binary) and calls the corresponding method
- `text` & `binary` are the io manipulators that change the stream state when applied to a stream.

Example Usage:

```cpp
A a;
std::cout << text << a;
std::cout << binary << a;
std::cout << a; // still in binary format
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Wfzc69MPT)

##### 2. Wrapper function

Another kind of io manipulators you'll also encounter in the standard library are wrappers that change the input / output of a single element.

Examples of this would be [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted), [`std::get_money`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_money), [`std::put_money`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money), etc...

Those functions only change the format for a single operation, in contrast to the above method that changes the format of all following input / output operations.
Example:

```cpp
std::cout << std::put_money(12.34); // will be formatted as monetary value
std::cout << 12.34; // normal double output
std::cout << std::quoted("foo"); // -> "foo"
std::cout << "foo"; // -> foo
```

You could e.g. implement it like this for your `A` class:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    void write_text(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "TEXT";
    }

    void write_binary(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "BINARY";
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& a) {
    std::ostream::sentry s{os};
    if(!s) return os;

    a.write_text(os);

    return os;
}

struct binary_impl { A const& a; };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, binary_impl const& b) {
    std::ostream::sentry s{os};
    if(!s) return os;

    b.a.write_binary(os);

    return os;
}

binary_impl binary(A const& a) {
    return { a };
}

// text is the default, so we need no wrapper
A const& text(A const& a) {
    return a;
}
```

- We essentially use a wrapper object (`binary_impl`) that implements a different `operator<<` for `A` objects.

Example Usage:

```cpp
A a;
std::cout << text(a);
std::cout << binary(a);
std::cout << a; // default is text format
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/dE5Wx4dsY)

---

The methods listed above are only the ones the standard library itself uses (and therefore probably the most recognized ones).

You can of course also create your own custom method for it, e.g. by using member methods that return objects that will serialize the object in a specific way:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    void write_text(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "TEXT";
    }

    void write_binary(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "BINARY";
    }

    struct as_text_t { A const& a; };
    struct as_binary_t { A const& a; };

    as_text_t as_text() const {
        return { *this };
    }

    as_binary_t as_binary() const {
        return { *this };
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A::as_text_t const& el) {
    std::ostream::sentry s{os};
    if(!s) return os;

    el.a.write_text(os);

    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A::as_binary_t const& el) {
    std::ostream::sentry s{os};
    if(!s) return os;

    el.a.write_binary(os);

    return os;
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
A a;
std::cout << a.as_text();
std::cout << a.as_binary();
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/sKxWcExan)